# I need to append the result of a sql select statement to another existing table

Tags: sql, t-sql

If I use the following code, it is not going to be used further because the table is getting created. But I just want to append the data instead of creating a new table every time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * INTO hist 
FROM source WHERE year(DOJ)< @year
```

Comment: What's your RDBMS? mySQL, MSSQL, Oracle?

Comment: i got it..:-) it's MSSQL.. by doing as follows..insert into hist select from source.

Answer (score 0):

Once the table exists you can `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` like this:

```
INSERT INTO 
    Hist 
SELECT DISTINCT
    * 
FROM 
    Source 
WHERE 
    YEAR(DOJ)< @year
```

You might need to change the `WHERE` clause to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT distinct * FROM source WHERE year(DOJ)< @year
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO Table2
(Column1, Column2)
SELECT distinct  (Column1, Column2) FROM source WHERE year(DOJ)< @year
```